# Creating a zip file on the fly from files stored on S3 using php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, zip

I have a Laravel web app in which users can upload files. These files can be sensitive and although they are stored on S3 they are only accessed via my webservers (streamed download). Once uploaded users may wish to download a selection of these files.

Previously when users went to download a selection of files my web server would download the files from S3, zip them locally and then send the zip down to the client. However once in production due to file sizes the server response would frequently time out.

As an alternative method I want to zip the files on the fly via [ZipStream](https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP) but I haven't had much luck. The zip file either ends up with corrupted files or is corrupted itself and incredibly small.

If it possible to pass a stream resource for a file on S3 to ZipStream and what is the best way to address my timeout issues?

I have tried several method my most recent two are as follows:

```
// First method using fopen
// Results in tiny corrupt zip files
if (!($fp = fopen("s3://{$bucket}/{$key}", 'r')))
{
    die('Could not open stream for reading');
}

$zip->addFileFromPath($file->orginal_filename, "s3://{$bucket}/{$key}");
fclose($fp);


// Second method tried get download the file from s3 before sipping
// Results in a reasonable sized zip file that is corrupt
$contents = file_get_contents("s3://{$bucket}/{$key}");

$zip->addFile($file->orginal_filename, $contents);
```

Each of these sits within a loop that goes through each files. After the loop I call $zip->finish().

Note I do not get any php errors just corrupt files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end the solution was to use signed S3 url's and curl to provide a file stream for ZipStream as demonstrated by [s3 bucket steam zip php](https://github.com/jmathai/s3-bucket-stream-zip-php). The resulting code edited from the aforementioned source is as follows:

```
public function downloadZip()
{
    // ...

    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
    $client = $s3->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient();
    $client->registerStreamWrapper();
    $expiry = "+10 minutes";

    // Create a new zipstream object
    $zip = new ZipStream($zipName . '.zip');

    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $filename = $file->original_filename;

        // We need to use a command to get a request for the S3 object
        //  and then we can get the presigned URL.
        $command = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
            'Key' => $file->path()
        ]);

        $signedUrl = $request = $client->createPresignedRequest($command, $expiry)->getUri();

        // We want to fetch the file to a file pointer so we create it here
        //  and create a curl request and store the response into the file
        //  pointer.
        // After we've fetched the file we add the file to the zip file using
        //  the file pointer and then we close the curl request and the file
        //  pointer.
        // Closing the file pointer removes the file.
        $fp = tmpfile();
        $ch = curl_init($signedUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $zip->addFileFromStream($filename, $fp);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    $zip->finish();
}
```

Note this requires curl and php-curl to be installed and functioning on your server.

Comment: Hi cubiclewar I tried your function and everything seems to be working fine except i am getting 0 byte files when adding to the zip file, i also tried the example function
fwrite($fp, 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');
$zip->addFileFromStream('goodbye.txt', $fp);
fclose($fp);
and getting the same thing. any help would be greatly appreciated. thanx

Comment: When you try fwrite are you removing the curl calls. When the file is present but is a 0 byte file it usually means your file pointer is not assigned.

Comment: on the example code you had above, there is no fwrite(); was there suppose to be

Comment: @rbz no curl is retrieving the file from S3 and writing it into a temporary file on local disk which is referenced by $fp.

Comment: yeah i kinda saw that with 
$ch = curl_init($signedUrl);
and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
still not sure what is happening, the signedUrl works on the browser to retrieve the content. i am not sure if it is a permissions thing though. thanx for all the help

Comment: @rbz have you checked that php-curl is installed and working. You should also ensure that curl is retrieving the file properly by either writing to disk or returning to browser after download. That way you can narrow where the problem is.

Comment: thanx @cubiclewar. let me try that.

Comment: @cubiclewar, what is the average file sizes you were dealing with?

Comment: @Godfrey the average is probably not very representative it varied greatly. Anywhere from a couple of KB to a GB.

Comment: @cubiclewar i have actually been developing a solution for the past 2 years for this same problem. Originally in PHP and Python but finally in Golang(Go). It should automate the whole process and works with most languages as it is an API.

Comment: This works greate with php s3 zip stream. But is there a way to password protect the zip file as well? Like when I download the file, it should have a password set as well?.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issues as @cubiclewar and investigated a little bit. I found that the most up to date solution to this doesn't need curl and it visible here on the wiki for the *maennchen/ZipStream-PHP/* library.

https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP/wiki/Symfony-example

```
use ZipStream;

//...

/**
 * @Route("/zipstream", name="zipstream")
 */
public function zipStreamAction()
{
    //sample test file on s3
    $s3keys = array(
      "ziptestfolder/file1.txt"
    );

    $s3Client = $this->get('app.amazon.s3'); //s3client service
    $s3Client->registerStreamWrapper(); //required

    //using StreamedResponse to wrap ZipStream functionality for files on AWS s3.
    $response = new StreamedResponse(function() use($s3keys, $s3Client)
    {

        // Define suitable options for ZipStream Archive.
        $opt = array(
                'comment' => 'test zip file.',
                'content_type' => 'application/octet-stream'
              );

        //initialise zipstream with output zip filename and options.
        $zip = new ZipStream\ZipStream('test.zip', $opt);

        //loop keys - useful for multiple files
        foreach ($s3keys as $key) {
            // Get the file name in S3 key so we can save it to the zip
            //file using the same name.
            $fileName = basename($key);

            //concatenate s3path.
            $bucket = 'bucketname'; //replace with your bucket name or get from parameters file.
            $s3path = "s3://" . $bucket . "/" . $key;

            //addFileFromStream
            if ($streamRead = fopen($s3path, 'r')) {
              $zip->addFileFromStream($fileName, $streamRead);
            } else {
              die('Could not open stream for reading');
            }
        }

        $zip->finish();

    });

    return $response;
}
```